# Structure defined in a dynamically loaded library

Tags: c++11, dynamic-linking

I am dynamically loading the cudart (Cuda Run Time Library) to access just the `cudaGetDeviceProperties` function. This one requires two arguments:

- A `cudaDeviceProp` structure which is defined in a header of the run time library;
- An integer which represents the device ID.

I am not including the `cuda_runtime.h` header in order to not get extra constants, macros, enum, class... that I do not want to use.

However, I need the `cudaDeviceProp` structure. Is there a way to get it without redefining it? I wrote the following code:

```
struct cudaDeviceProp;

class CudaRTGPUInfoDL
{   
    typedef int(*CudaDriverVersion)(int*);
    typedef int(*CudaRunTimeVersion)(int*);
    typedef int(*CudaDeviceProperties)(cudaDeviceProp*,int);

public:
    struct Properties
    {
        char   name[256];                           /**< ASCII string identifying device */
        size_t totalGlobalMem;                      /**< Global memory available on device in bytes */
        size_t sharedMemPerBlock;                   /**< Shared memory available per block in bytes */
        int    regsPerBlock;                        /**< 32-bit registers available per block */
        int    warpSize;                            /**< Warp size in threads */
        size_t memPitch;                            /**< Maximum pitch in bytes allowed by memory copies */
        /*... Tons of members follow..*/
    };

public:
CudaRTGPUInfoDL();
~CudaRTGPUInfoDL();

int getCudaDriverVersion();
int getCudaRunTimeVersion();
const Properties& getCudaDeviceProperties();

private:
    QLibrary                library;

private:
    CudaDriverVersion       cuDriverVer;
    CudaRunTimeVersion      cuRTVer;
    CudaDeviceProperties    cuDeviceProp;

    Properties              properties;
};
```

As everybody can see, I simply "copy-pasted" the declaration of the structure.

In order to get the GPU properties, I simply use this method:

```
const CudaRTGPUInfoDL::Properties& CudaRTGPUInfoDL::getCudaDeviceProperties()
{
    // Unsafe but needed.
    cuDeviceProp(reinterpret_cast<cudaDeviceProp*>(&properties), 0);
    return properties;
}
```

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Be aware that following the pointer you generate here `cuDeviceProp(reinterpret_cast<cudaDeviceProp*>(&properties), 0);` is undefined behavior, but is likely to work in current compilers.  The next compiler update?  Who knows.

Comment: I will find another way. I will include the required header and don't bother with that as Toby suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need the structure to be complete, you should define it (probably by including the appropriate header).

If you're just going to be passing around references or pointers, such as in the method you show, then it doesn't need to be complete and can just be forward declared:

```
class cudaDeviceProp;
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I need it to be complete. I thought there could be a magical way to do it without including headers.